# Multi-core processor - what is the meaning of this?

Tags: central-processing-unit, multi-core

I am baffled by the terminologies like `Core i3`, `Core i`5 etc. Does `Core i3` means **three physical CPU's (three physical Chips)? or three cpu's in a SINGLE CHIP?**

I did try to find this information online, but my doubts still remain the same, can anyone help me understand this in simple words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers 3, 5 and 7 in i3, i5 and i7 are just part of the branding -- they aren't actually counting 3, 5 or 7 of anything, any more than the old 80386 CPUs actually had 80,386 of anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, why these companies confuse ppl! Ur comment made me laugh.